# Differentiate respect to $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x^2+2x+1)^3$ 
let u=$x^2+2x+1$  
 $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$ or $2x+2$ $\frac{dy}{dx}=3u^2 $ 
if $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$ then 
$3(x^2+2x+1)^2 (2x)$ 
answer is $6x(x^2+2x+1) $ 
 
Or 
if $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x+2$ then 
$3(x^2+2x+1)^2 (2x+2)$ 
$6x(x^2+2x+1)+2$

however the right answer is $6(x+1)^5$
can please help me out? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: $\dfrac{du}{dx} = 2x+2$ and replace $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ and $2x+2=2\cdot(x+1)$ in $3(x^2+2x+1)^2 (2x+2)$.

Comment: @SbSangpi I don't understand the two cases you make for the derivative of $u$ wrt $x$. Are you trying to guess or what are the two cases?

Comment: yea.I'm confuse with du/dx that's why I try to guess one by one to get answer!

Comment: Where did the $y$ come from?

Comment: @copper: it was $y=u^3$ (it should be separated from 2x+2 and written... :-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by Chain rule :

$f'(x)=3(x^2+2x+1)^2 \cdot(x^2+2x+1)'=3\cdot(x+1)^4\cdot(2x+2)=$

$=6\cdot(x+1)^4\cdot(x+1)=6(x+1)^5$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{du}{dx}&=2x+2=2(x+1)\\x^2+2x+1 &=(x+1)^2\\(x^a)^b&=x^{ab}\end{align}$$